# How would you translate events like 'International Women's Day', 'Earth Day' etc.... Are these Sondertage?

Tags: translation

I'm researching these for a project at work and don't know how to refer to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These events are generally named as

> Aktionstag

If such an event is on the appropriate list of the United Nations, it is called

> Welttag

Comment: "Welttage werden neben den UN zunehmend auch von anderen Organisationen wie etwa der Katholischen Kirche (z. B. den Welttag der sozialen Kommunikationsmittel) und PR-Agenturen ausgerufen. " (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welttag)

Comment: While `Aktionstag` might well be the best word to refer to such days in general, be aware that it does not neccessarily imply a *world-wide*, *annually recurring* special day with a *philanthropic* theme. A local business might for example just as well declare an `Aktionstag` or several `Aktionstage` to promote a particular (range of) product(s) and/or service(s).

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia calls them ["Welttage"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welttag).

There seem to be more than 100 of them.

---

*If every third or fourth day is one of them, and if other organisations have their own "world days" as well, ISTM the whole idea gets a little inflationary, but that is just my personal opinion.*